# How to redirect https://domainname.com to https://www.domainname.com in Application Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway, azure-dns

I have a secured website (using https certificate and WAF) balanced by the Azure application gateway. The problem is that when browsing the website without **www** then I got the error message that this site is not secured while if I add [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com) I get the secured website. I tried in the application gateway a feature called Host Type Multiple/Wildcard as in the following screenshot
[image: Multiple/Wildcard]

But that did not work. So the question is:
How to redirect https://domaionname.com to https://www.domainname.com

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

Once you create Application gateway and point it’s IP address to your custom domain name such as to redirect  `https://domaionname.com` to  `https://www.domainname.com`  you can add another listener with hostname “`www.example.com`” and make sure that the previous listener with hostname “`example.com`” redirects to the newly added listener.

Try to add another listener HTTPS like below:

[image]

So, 2 HTTPs listeners with hostnames - one without www and one with www. Add a rule to redirect without www HTTPS listener to with www HTTPS listener.

And another rule to make sure that with www HTTPS listener is bound to a backend pool to serve the traffic like below:

Application gateway rule to redirect the listener 1 to listener 2.

[image]

[image]

I created a new rule for listener 2 to use the HTTPS settings to send traffic to my backend pool.

[image]

Now Application gateway for domain name redirect to **`https://www.domainname.com`** successfully like below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am getting an error in Azure when creating a new listener: Failed to save configuration changes to application gateway 'my-application-gateway'. Error: Two Http Listeners of Application Gateway app-https-listener and app-https-listener2 are using the same Frontend Port

Comment: This error usually occurs if you are public and private listener are using the same port. You shouldcreate a new Front End IP Configuration using a different port, and you can  direct the traffic to the same backend port.

Comment: Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/452279/error-when-creating-listener-on-application-gatewa?orderby=newest